# How to modify validation message of Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

Is there any way to customize an error message for this?

```
    request()->validate([
        'emp-status' => 'required'
    ]);
```

What I want it to return is like 
**hey this is a custom message**

Comment: If you have given name employee status to the input field, then this error will show your input name which will be required, otherwise you can check laravel documentation for further custom messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this....

```
// resources/lang/en/validation.php

'custom' => [
    'emp-status' => [
        'required' => 'hey this is a custom message',
    ],
]
```

You can also do it in this way...

```
$rules = [
    'emp-status' => 'required'
];

$customMessages = [
    'required' => 'hey :attribute is a custom message'
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

You can, even more, customize your code.

```
$customMessages = [
    'emp-status.required' => 'hey this is a custom message'
];
```

Comment: following that, should I remove my existing validation?

Comment: see updated, actually you have to pass attribute name, your validation remains the same.